# Can an Elementary Matrix's Inverse's Determinant = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Can someone explain to me why an elementary matrix's inverse determinant cannot equal 0?
Or can it? Is there some theorem to elementary matrix inverses?

THANKS FOR YOUR INSIGHT! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a matrice is inversible, the determinant is non nul. The inverse of a inversible matrice is by definition inversible, then the determinant is no nul too. So the response to your question is of course no !!

Comment: An explanation of [elementary matrices being invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) would better address the Question.